# Woocommerce api integration post not working in lumen

Tags: woocommerce, lumen

I am currently working on a project that needs integration with the woocommerce api. I am writing the endpoints using routers in lumen. I have successfully done the get methods. For the post http the response is throwing Not Allowed Method.

Below is my sample post code:

```
$router->post('/post_order', function () {
    //$name = $request->input('name');


    $woocommerce = new Client(
        env('WOOCOMMERCE_URL'),
        env('WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY'),
        env('WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET'),
        [
            'wp_api' => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v2',
        ]
    );

    $data = [
        'payment_method' => 'bacs',
        'payment_method_title' => 'Direct Bank Transfer',
        'set_paid' => true,
        'billing' => [
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe',
            'address_1' => '969 Market',
            'address_2' => '',
            'city' => 'San Francisco',
            'state' => 'CA',
            'postcode' => '94103',
            'country' => 'US',
            'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
            'phone' => '(555) 555-5555'
        ],
        'shipping' => [
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe',
            'address_1' => '969 Market',
            'address_2' => '',
            'city' => 'San Francisco',
            'state' => 'CA',
            'postcode' => '94103',
            'country' => 'US'
        ],
        'line_items' => [
            [
                'product_id' => 93,
                'quantity' => 2
            ],
            [
                'product_id' => 22,
                'variation_id' => 23,
                'quantity' => 1
            ]
        ],
        'shipping_lines' => [
            [
                'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
                'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
                'total' => 10
            ]
        ]
    ];


    $order = $woocommerce->post('orders', $data);

    return response()->json($order);
});
```

Comment: You should quote the full errors in your post, not just vaguely mention them.

Comment: Here is the error screenshot

Comment: (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RoutesRequests.php (line 228)
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(2, array('POST')))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 164)
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
in RoutesRequests.php (line 413)
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 166)
at Application->dispatch(null)
in RoutesRequests.php (line 107)
at Application->run()
in index.php (line 28)

Comment: [Edit] your post; don't leave essential info in comments.